# On hover, fill in background color of div/box from corner of box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fill in the background color of a div/box from the corner of the box and find a way to specify which corner to start the "filling in."

I have a box which does fill in at hover, but it only does so from the top, bottom, left or right.

```css
#txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2vw;
}

#box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  background-color: black;
  color: ghostwhite;
}

#box:hover {
  color: deepskyblue;
  transition: color 0.25s ease;
}

#box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background: ghostwhite;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}

#box:hover::after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span id="txt">
        TEXT
      </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you should have a look at `transform: rotate(X)` where X is an angle in degree. The after element is an moving rectangle. If you want to start at a corner, you have to rotate your rectangle. Also make sure the box has òverflow: hidden`to mask your rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#box:after {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    transform-origin: top left; /* animation will start from top left corner */
}

#box:hover::after {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

Origin for all corners:

```
transform-origin: top right;
transform-origin: top left;
transform-origin: bottom left;
transform-origin: bottom right;
```

Comment: Can u suggest how to fill background having some border radius (gostwhite color should fill like a bubble from one corner)

Comment: @bollam_rohith `border-radius: 100%` on `after` should work

Answer (score 1):

Use transform to position correctly the element, with rotate and translate. Then animate the height of the element to fill the square.

The size of the ::after is made to 142% is the rounded up value of the hypotenuse. Since it is bigger, it will grow out of the container so we set overflow:hidden on the container.

To change the corner from which all this happens, you need to change top,left, transform-origin and the rotate degree.

```css
#txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2vw;
}

#box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  background-color: black;
  color: ghostwhite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box:hover {
  color: deepskyblue;
  transition: color 0.25s ease;
}

#box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 142%;
  height: 0%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-50%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background: ghostwhite;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: height 0.25s ease;
}

#box:hover::after {
  height: 142%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-50%);
  color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span id="txt">
        TEXT
      </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonderful !!!! Can u suggest how to fill background having some border radius (gostwhite color should fill like a bubble from one corner)

Comment: Adding `border-radius:100%` to the box:after should do the trick (if I understand what you mean)

Answer (score 0):

just change your css transform. For example, setting

`translate(-50%,0%) scale(0,0);`

and then

`translate(0%,0%) scale(1,1);`

will animate from the bottom, left corner ...
of course, the pair of transformations depends *both* on the source corner *and* on the wanted initial condition of the box

Answer (score 0):

Use `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` to place the box in the corner, then reset the values to 0 on hover. Don't forget to add `overflow: hidden;` to your box. Here is a working example for top-right corner:

```css
#txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2vw;
}

#box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  background-color: black;
  color: ghostwhite;
     overflow: hidden;
}

#box:hover {
  color: deepskyblue;
  transition: color 0.25s ease;
}

#box:after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 101%;
     left: 101%;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     transform-origin: bottom;
     background: ghostwhite;
     z-index: -1;
     transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

#box:hover::after {
     color: deepskyblue;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span id="txt">
        TEXT
      </span>
</div>
```